# VB.net Outlook get custom folder mail

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook, outlook-2007, mapi

Hey all i am using this code here:

```
Dim tempInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim InboxItems As Outlook.Items
Dim newMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim customFolder As String = "Mainbox - testing here"

tempApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
tempInbox = tempApp.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders(customFolder)
InboxItems = tempInbox.Items

For Each newMail In InboxItems
 ......
```

In order to grab that users email that i have. Problem is that the name of the folder **Mainbox - testing here** was not found *(The operation failed. An object could not be found.)* and errors on this line:

```
tempInbox = tempApp.GetNamespace("Mapi").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders(customFolder)
```

If i use a folder within my email box:

```
Mainbox - My Name Here
  A Folder 1
  A Folder 2
```

it works just fine using the code above...

What would i be missing in order to find this custom folder?

The folder structor looks like this:

```
Mainbox - My Name Here
  A Folder 1
  A Folder 2
Archive Folders
  Deleted Items
  Send Items
Mainbox - testing here
  Inbox
Vault - My Name Here
  A Folder 1
  A Folder 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code assumes that folder is on the same level as the Inbox.

Use Namespace.Folders.Item(customFolder)

Comment: Ok changed it and it did find that folder but its not coming up with a count for **Inbox** within the folder? How can i get the **Inbox** mail inside **Mailbox - testing here**?

Comment: You can use TopLevelFolder.Folders("Inbox") or you can use Store.GetDefaultFolder instead of Namespace.GetDefaultFolder.